# Setup angular cli production build tfs

Tags: angular, tfs, angular-cli

Locally my project builds fine with ng build --prod but if I set it up on tfs (team foundation server) with the following powershell script it fails with some errors.

ps script:

```
npm install
npm run ng build --prod
```

tfs build output:

- [1m[33mWARNING in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/scss/style.scss
- autoprefixer: D:\a\1\s\src\scss\style.scss:7468:3: Replace transition-property to transition, because Autoprefixer could not support any cases of transition-property and other transition-*
  @ ./src/scss/style.scss 4:14-203
  2017-04-30T07:17:51.9419669Z  @ multi ./~/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme.css ./~/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css ./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./src/scss/style.scss[39m[22m
- [error]  0% compiling 10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active multi D:\a\1\s\src\main.ts
- [error]Process completed with exit code 0 and had 3 error(s) written to the error stream.

Comment: Try to remove local node_modules folder and run npm I and build again. Will you see the same error?

Comment: Locally it builds fine but It does not build on team foundation server.

Comment: I see but maybe your packages versions are different with tfs. I had the same issue. It worked on locale machine because i used old version and didn't update local node_modules

Comment: @yurzui I tried and it builds fine but not on tfs. Which build host do you use and is your script the same as mine?

Comment: I know that it could be run on your local server, could you please test it run this file or command manually on your build agent server. Your project is mapping down to the path `D:\a\1\s\`.

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT I'm sorry but how can I run it on my build agent? I'm using the hosted one on tfs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works now, I removed the powershell script and added seperate tasks in the build process.

- npm install (standard one)
- npm install -g @angular/cli (command line)
- ng build --prod (command line)

Update based on comment:

You can also use: npm run ng build -- --prod. This way you don't have to install angular/cli.

Comment: are you using 3 powershell scripts? (1 ps script 1 line) ?

Comment: @nerlijma I'm not using ps script at the moment. Just cmd commands

Comment: does this install the cli every time a build runs?

Comment: Yes. Its not the best thing but it works for the moment.

Comment: I tried the same thing, but I keep getting the error: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Siddhant: you may have to set PATH variable in environment variables for ng commands.

Comment: Actually, the CLI was not getting installed properly, so instead, made a one time installation of the CLI on my TFS server.
Will upgrade it as and when required.
Thanks all the same [Sreekumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451221/sreekumar)..!

Comment: Would it not be possible to run the ng command from the node_modules/.bin directory?

Comment: Thanks for the `npm run ng build --`! This saves a lot of PATH specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

I was doing the same as the marked answer, but it bugged me that it's always installing angular-cli globally everytime. So i just switched that a bit like this:

```
node $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod -op $(Build.BinariesDirectory) -v
```

now, after npm installs all the deps, it's gonna install cli too, and then just use that one.

Answer (score 2):

Add npm Task (`Add Task >> Package >> npm`) with below configuration

[image]

Comment: this worked for me in a way. I was getting a different error but I just tried using version 0.* in tfs build and it worked