# Unable to set up Angular SIT build on TFS

Tags: angular, tfs, build-automation

I am unable to set up Angular SIT build on TFS. I am pretty new to Angular.

In my company, they are checking-in Angular solution using TFS (neighter VSTS not Git). I am getting build failed error. But, I may not be able to show the build error details due to company security restrictions.

I googled for my problem, and found one solution in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704445/setup-angular-cli-production-build-tfs). But, these suggestions did not work to me.

Can anyone please suggest me where can I learn and understand quickly on how to do Angular SIT build on TFS? Please note that I can use ONLY TFS, and I am NOT allowed to install any other software to get this work done.

Comment: Without relevant diagnostic information (such as the error messages you're receiving) there is no way anyone can help you.

Comment: If you could not show the build error details due to company security restrictions. Instead of sharing the public website here. Your team could contact the official  Technical Support from Microsoft VSTS/TFS.  How to contact please refer this link-- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/support/

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Your suggestion may work well to me.

Comment: @Ashokkumar Glad to hear this, if the issue finally be solved, feel free to share the solution here, which will also helps others in the community.